# How to docker-compose run in windows?

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose, boot2docker

How to use this command in windows 10 familly :

```
docker-compose run api composer install --no-interaction
```

Example:

```
docker-compose run api composer install --no-interaction
- Interactive mode is not yet supported on Windows.
Please pass the -d flag when using `docker-compose run`.
```

Is it possible ?
Do you have an example ?

Answer (score 3):

The interactive mode support for docker-compose on Windows is tracked by [issue 2836](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/2836) which proposes some alternatives:

- Use bash from within the container:

  ```
  docker exec -it MY_CONTAINER bash
  ```
- Use a [docker-compose-run script](https://gist.github.com/rodrigobaron/64ea67f374b36db70542e6e3636c98b1) by [Rodrigo Baron](https://github.com/rodrigobaron):

Script ( put the function in `~/.zshrc` or `~/.bashrc` in a Windows git bash shell for instance):

```
#!/bin/bash

function docker-compose-run() {
        if [ "$1" = "-f" ] || [ "$1" = "--file" ] ; then
                docker exec -i $(docker-compose -f $2 ps $3 |grep -m 1 $3 | cut -d ' ' -f1) "${@:4}"
        else
                docker exec -i $(docker-compose ps $1 | grep -m 1 $1 | cut -d ' ' -f1) "${@:2}"
        fi
}

docker-compose-run "$@"
```

Usage:

usage:

```
docker-compose-run web rspec

# or:

docker-compose-run -f docker-compose.development.yml web rspec
```

Comment: Thanks. I can do docker-compose run -d api bin/console d:s:u --force for example it's working ! but How execute : docker-compose run -d vendor/bin/phpunit with the result ?

Comment: @user3231191 Just to let you know I don't have an immediate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Simpler alternative is to use option `-d` and to get logs

```
docker-compose run -rm <service> <command>
```

is replaced by:

```
docker-compose-run <service> <command>
```

For this to work, add this snippet in your `~/.bashrc` :

```
docker-compose-run() {
    CONTAINER_NAME=$(docker-compose run -d $@)
    docker logs -f $CONTAINER_NAME
    docker rm $CONTAINER_NAME
}
```